# Adding Several Items To A Linked-List

Tags: java, linked-list, data-collection

I am creating an implementation of a linked list and am having trouble with the add method. After testing it with several entries, my `size()` method always returns 1. what am i doing wrong.

```
public class Node {

    public int data;
    public Node next;

       public Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }       
}


public class LinkedList {

    public Node first;
    public Node last;

    public LinkedList(){
        first = null;
        last = null;
    } 

    public void add(int data){    
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if(first == null){
            first = newNode;        
        } else {
            add(first, newNode);
        }                  
    }

    public void add(Node currentNode, Node newNode){

        if(currentNode.next != null){
            add(currentNode.next, newNode);
        }
        currentNode.next = newNode;
    }   
        public int size(){        
        if(first == null){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return size(first);
        }        
    }
    public int size(Node currentNode){
        //Count Starts At One Because First = 1.
        int count = 1;        
        if(currentNode == null){
            return count;
        }
        else {
            count++;
            return size(currentNode.next);
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, don't make edits directly in your question when you find bugs. That will completely invalidate your question and all the associated answers.

Comment: Especially if those edits are pointless or just plain wrong.

Comment: I reverted the edits that modified code (not formatting). But kudos on making your code nicer and easier to read. That is very helpful and you should keep doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `else` in the 2-arg form of `add`. As it stands,

```
if(currentNode.next != null){
    add(currentNode.next, newNode);
}
currentNode.next = newNode;
```

will always add the new node to `first` **and** to all the other nodes in the list. If `currentNode.next = newNode` appears in an `else` clause, it will be added correctly only to the end.

Additionally, your `size` method always returns `1` because the final branch always returns `1`. To fix this, change

```
count++;
return size(currentNode.next);
```

to

```
return 1 + size(currentNode.next);
```

Also, replace `return count;` with `return 1;`.

Basically, your implementation is almost correct. `size(Node)` should return the size of the list starting with that node. If the node does not have a `next`, the size is 1. Otherwise, its the current node (1) + the size of the remaining tail.

You should make the 2-arg versions of `add` and the 1-arg version of `size` `private` since you don't want to expose the internals of your list to the public (in fact, the `Node` class should be a private class as well).

Additionally, you never use the `last` field of your class. You can either remove it, or use it to avoid the need for recursion completely in `add`. In the latter case, you will have to update it correctly with every new addition.

Comment: Thanks for that Mad Physicist. The Node Class is a separate private class, I just posted it up there for viewing purposes. (I should have noted that.).

Comment: No worries. The exact internal structure is not that important. I assumed it was public because it reads `public class Node ...` :)

Answer (score 0):

In place of `return size(currentNode.next);` try this `return count + size(currentNode.next);`

It will fix the count problem given that, the list is fine. But checking your code at a glance looks like the list addition code is also buggy.